# propType [name] is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

```js
import styled from 'styled-components'
import propTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'

const Checkbox = ({ className, checked, ...props }) => (
  <CheckboxContainer className={className}>
    <HiddenCheckbox checked={checked} {...props} />
    <StyledCheckbox checked={checked}>
      <Icon viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <polyline points="20 6 9 17 4 12" />
      </Icon>
    </StyledCheckbox>
  </CheckboxContainer>
)
    
Checkbox.propTypes = {
  checked: propTypes.boolean,
  className: propTypes.string,
}
```

I have this component and I'm always getting this error: error  propType "className" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration  react/require-default-props

I don't know how to fix it any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's explained in the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values

As you are marking this prop as not required it is asking you to put a default in case the prop is missing.

So, something like this (but default values depends on you):

```js
Checkbox.defaultProps = {
  checked: false,
  className: null,
}
```

Comment: @dan-klasson what's the value on commenting a 2yo question saying that "is wrong", without thinking at the React version out at that date. Also adding a reference to TypeScript, which is not a React standard and never mentioned by the author. This is StackOwerflow: you can add your own answer talking about the deprecation, or edit my old answer

Comment: sorry, i thought this was tagged as typescript.

Comment: (As of Dec 2023) keep in mind the support of defaultProps will be removed in a future major release. They recommend you to use JS default parameters instead!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to disable this type of warning, just update your `rules` inside `.eslintrc.json`

```json
"rules": {
  "react/require-default-props": "off"
}
```

Alternatively, you can mark it as a warning

```json
"rules": {
  "react/require-default-props": "warn"
}
```

Comment: is this the best practice? new to type script so I am wondering what the implications are for disabling this rule

Comment: @128KB you don't have to disable it you can mark it as a warning. So, it want be treated as an error with red highlighting. It will show warning (orange highlighting). That's what I have used in most of my projects

Comment: @128KB Usually disabling the rules is not recommended but, defaultProps will be removed in the next major release so, in our project we disabled this rule and changed to using JS default parameters instead!